# i386 architecture deprecated in MacOS error

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I'm completely new to the Mac environment and I've only been using it for a few hours. When I run a shell script, I get the following error-

```
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr", referenced from:
  ___darwintrace_setup in darwintrace.o
  "__DefaultRuneLocale", referenced from:
  _check_interpreter in proc.o
  "___error", referenced from:
      __dt_access in access.o
      __dt_close in close.o
  ___darwintrace_setup_tls in darwintrace.o
  ___darwintrace_setup in darwintrace.o
  __dt_dup2 in dup2.o
  __dt_mkdir in mkdir.o
  __dt_open in open.o
  ...
  "___getdirentries64", referenced from:
      __interpose___getdirentries64 in readdir.o
  "___maskrune", referenced from:
      _check_interpreter in proc.o
  "___snprintf_chk", referenced from:
      ___darwintrace_sandbox_check in darwintrace.o
      ___darwintrace_log_op in darwintrace.o
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      ___darwintrace_setup in darwintrace.o
      ___darwintrace_is_in_sandbox in darwintrace.o
      ___darwintrace_sandbox_check in darwintrace.o
      ___darwintrace_log_op in darwintrace.o
      _check_interpreter in proc.o
      __dt_getdirentries64 in readdir.o
     __dt_getdirentries in readdir.o
  ...

  "_unlink", referenced from:
      __interpose_unlink in unlink.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [darwintrace.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How do I remove i386 architecture from Xcode? How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Using xcode 9.4 or 9.4.1, which is the last version to support 32 bit build and valid on Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is that apple has removed to ability to compile 32 bit programs on macos with xcode10

source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes

Answer (score 0):

modified the CMakeLists.txt    delete the i386 words
; on the last mac os not support the.  i386 software complies